# How to play steam workshop content in trackmania 2 canyon?

Tags: steam, trackmania-2

I subscribed to three canyon maps. Then restarted the game.
It updated the subscribed content.

But I don't see the subscribed map anywhere!

Where to find those maps so I can play them?

Answer (score 4):

Local Game → Single Map → Downloaded → *author name*